# создать класс без `class`

Tags: python, python-3.x

мне дали задание где нужно реализовать класс и некоторые методы, это я сделал, но там было условие что это надо сделать без `class` т.е. я не могу писать так

```
class MyClass:
   ...
```

помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Попробуйте для этого использовать dict по аналогии с объектами javascript. Правда у вас получится прототипное ООП, а не наследуемое. Что именно необходимо реализовать?

Comment: Есть специальный метакласс `type`, экземпляры которого являются классами — можно создать класс через него: `MyClass = type('MyClass', (object,), {})`

Comment: @andreymal а как добавлять методы?

Comment: Пихать заранее созданные функции в словарь который в третьем аргументе, например. Ну или можно после создания пихать в уже созданный класс `MyClass.foo = foo`

Comment: `MyClass = object()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот пример

```
def double(x):
    return x*2

like_list = type("List", (list,), {"z":5, "double":double})
d = like_list("fdgfdgrtg")
print(d)
```

выдаст

```
['f', 'd', 'g', 'f', 'd', 'g', 'r', 't', 'g']
```

а
`d.z`
выдаст 5

проверьте что будет с

```
d.double()
```

Обращаю внимание, что первый аргумент функции передаваемой в словаре как будущий метод воспринимается как self, это если нужны более сложные операции.
И да - `__init__()` не пробовал пока добавлять. Так что все переменные  -  классовые ))

Answer (score 5):

получился такой код:

```
def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.x)

def double(self):
    self.x *= 2

MyClass = type("MyClass", (), {"__init__": __init__,
                               "__str__": __str__,
                               "double": double})

obj = MyClass(5)
print(obj)
obj.double()
print(obj)
```

Answer (score 4):

Занятный костыль. Можно воспользоваться функцией как объектом:

```
from types import MethodType

def f():
    return

f.param = 'val'

f.method = MethodType(lambda obj, x: print(obj.param + x), f)


# Теперь f не функция, a класс прикольно, да?
f.method('ue')
```

out:

```
value
```

Спасибо большое @mkkik за подсказку.

Comment: В такой «метод» не передаётся self, так что классом это всё назвать трудно)

Comment: @andreymal Ты прав. Чуть позже подумаю, как это сделать, а то и спрошу ;)

Comment: Подсказка: `from types import MethodType; f.method = MethodType(lambda obj, x: print(obj.param + x), f); f.method("alala") # -> valalala`

Comment: @mkkik ;) thx!!!

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с `exec` и `eval`:

```
def get_class(name: str) -> type:
    exec(f'''\
class {name}:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def double(self):
        return self.x * 2
    ''')
    return eval(name)


MyClass = get_class('MyClass')
print(MyClass)
# <class '__main__.MyClass'>

x = MyClass(10)
print(x.double())
# 20
```